# how to install debuginfo packages from vmlinux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, perf, debug-information

I am building my own kernel with following options set.

```
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
```

So I assume that the generated vmlinux file will have all the required debuginfo.

I installed that kernel in a machine and put the vmlinux file under /boot/.
However, when I tried to do a perf annotate it does not show the source code along side the assembly code. It only shows the assembly code and c function names not the entire source code(I have tried toggling "s" during annotate).

Here are my perf commands.

```
#perf record -g -a -e cycles:k sleep 5
#perf report -f -g -s symbol
#perf annotate -f -s <kernel function name> > annotate_<kernel_function>.txt
```

What am I missing here ?  Do I need to install debuginfo packages separately ?

Regards,
Atish

Comment: what distro are you running?

Comment: Fedora 23 and building the kernel from the latest kernel source code.

Comment: debuginfo packages are bound with the same version of the kernel, so if you want debug the kernel you compiled from latest source, you will need install the debuginfo packages built by this compile, not from the repo.

Comment: Sorry If my question was not clear enough. I am trying to install the debuginfo packages from the my built kernel only. But I do not know how. 
Only the source rpm/binary rpm files are generated. Where are the debuginfo packages ?

Comment: If you are building with rpm, you can find the debuginfo packages at $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I do not see anything else other than the kernel rpm file. Here is my kernel build command. Am I missing anything ?

**make oldconfig  && time make -j 120 binrpm-pkg**

Comment: Oh, you are make rpm this way. I thought you build via rpmbuild kernel.spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binrpm-pkg target to build kernel rpm does not generate debuginfo because it disabled generation of debuginfo packages, you can try do this, open `scripts/package/mkspec` in your kernel source tree, and search for a line `echo "%define debug_package %{nil}"`, comment or remove this line, and try to build again.

The reason is that this line explicitly tell rpmbuild that skip debuginfo packages.

See the link:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9256d5a308c95a50c6e85d682492ae1f86a70f9b/scripts/package/mkspec#L45